# Flash Gallery with mp3 on every item

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I am trying to make a Flash movie that contains movie clip ***(lets say "root" for the example)*** with multiple movie clips ***("children").*** Every children has a mp3 player.
Now, I have set a children **mp3 play button** and wrote the following action:

```
 movieClip_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame);
 function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndPlay(2);
 }
```

Until here it works just fine.
Now I would like to set that every time that the play button clicked on any children the root will stop move until the **mp3** file will finish to play.

what is the best way for making it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SoundChannel` class sends the `flash.events.Event.SOUND_COMPLETE` event when an mp3 finishes to play. So, children can redispatch this event and the root can listen it and makes that you want.

**Update**

Impelentation of this method depends on implementation of mp3 player. For an example:

```
//In a child
var sound:Sound = new Sound();   
var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("my_sound.mp3");

// Sound events listeners

soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundChannel_soundCompleteHandler);
sound.load(request);
soundChannel = sound.play();

soundChannel_soundCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
    dispatchEvent(event);
}

//Somewhere in the root
mp3Child.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, mp3Child_soundCompleteHandler);
```

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you saying but I really doen't know how to perform that. Can you please help me with that?